# Remote Desktop - Windows to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: server, remote-desktop

I'm trying to connect to a remote server which is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I've just installed `ubuntu-desktop` on the server and now I'm trying to access it from my home computer, which is running Windows. How can I actually achieve this?

I've already tried to download 'xrdp'. This is what happens:

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install xrdp
 Unable to locate package xrdp
```

So what else can I use?

Comment: There are softwares like ssh or teamviewer (since you mentioned desktop) for remote access.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt-get update` first, then run `sudo apt-get install xrdp`

Comment: @Raphael I can access the server with SSH without problem, what I would like to do is access it with the GUI from my window computer.

I'm trying to install and use teamviewer via Terminal now

Comment: @AndroidDev that's what I've done :) Keep getting "Unable to locate package xrdp"

Comment: @Fre - Then `teamviewer` is the best you have got. Download it from there website and install it - `cd Downloads; wget -c https://download.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_i386.deb; sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_i386.deb; sudo apt-get install -f`.

Comment: @Fre - If after running these commands you still get an error, then you have a big problem with the repo lists. http://paste.ubuntu.com/23051993/

Comment: @AndroidDev thanks! Worked that way :) Right now I'm connected to my desktop server! Add your answer and I will gladly accept it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently, the OP's install didn't have all the repos enabled.

In order to enable them and install `xrdp`, you need to open a terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and run these commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install xrdp
```